# Node.js move heavy CPU bound task

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have a function that calls it-self recursively based on parameters passed. This function is calling another functions at the end that *can* be very CPU intensive because it deals with a set of N objects and doing heavy `string` manipulation. When N is large enough it slows the application. Moving the `string` manipulations to the event loop using timers doesn't work, because it'll still slow the application from executing code that follows this loop. I thought of spawning another node instance using `child_process` but I don't think it's a good solution either because depending on the configuration passes to the first function, this function can be called many times meaning a-lot of spawned node.js processes.

Here's a code example that illustrates the problem:

```
function Fun(opts) {
    // depending on opts we call HeavyCPU alot
    while (...) {
        var set = ...;
        HeavyCPU(set)
    }
}

function HEAVYCPU(var set) {
    // Heavy CPU task - string manipulations
}

module.exports = Fun;
```

if I spawn child process this way:

```
// fun.js
var cp = require('child_process');
function Fun(opts) {
    // depending on opts we call HeavyCPU alot
    while (...) {
        var set = ...;
        var child = cp.fork('./heavycpu', set);
    }
}

module.exports = Fun;

// heavycpu.js
function HEAVYCPU(var set) {
    // Heavy CPU task - string manipulations
}
```

I could still end up with lots of spawned processes depending on the while statement which is dependent on `opts`.

What can I do in such case ?

Comment: Why dont you spawn another child process and then call `HEAVYCPU` in it rather than spawning processes in it.

Comment: @CodeSpirit but I could potentially call `HEAVYCPU` lots of time depending on `opts`, this could potentially make me spawn alot of child processes

Comment: I mean: start process, do your `HEAVYCPU` calls, end process.

Comment: @CodeSpirit I don't see how I wouldn't end up with lots of spawned processes this way. I've edited the question to show you.

Comment: @Jorayen usually, when there are lot of compute heavy task that you have no control over needs to be performed it'd be best to have some kind of queue manager to handle it and based on your machine's capability you can run finite amount of N and queue the rest until the priors are done. This isn't particular to `node` but to pretty much all the system unless someone has any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple spawning of child processes you could format your arguments and call the while process in `HEAVYCPU` (your child task).

fun.js

```
var cp = require('child_process');
function Fun(opts) {
    var arguments = processOptions(opts) //processOptions is just an example
    var child = cp.fork('./heavycpu', arguments );
}

module.exports = Fun;
```

heavycpu.js

```
function HEAVYCPU(var set) {
    while(...) {
      //Here goes the actual processing code
    }
}
```

If you dont want to mix you `HEAVYCPU` code with iterating the arguments you could create a wrapper function (which then is called in the child process) which processes the supplied arguments and then calls `HEAVYCPU`.

You could also send each argument to your process:

> The child_process.fork() method is a special case of child_process.spawn() used specifically to spawn new Node.js processes. Like child_process.spawn(), a ChildProcess object is returned. The returned ChildProcess will have an additional communication channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back and forth between the parent and child. See child.send() for details.

[Child Processes Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

Comment: well could you recommend a lightweight worker queue module that will let me launch Node.js processes of standalone functions like my `HEAVYCPU` without separating it to different modules?

Comment: I also would want to point that `Fun` and `HEAVYCPU` are functions of the same class. `HEAVYCPU` emits events from this class instances, so separating it to different module would not be good because of the event emitted that is expected to be emitted from the original class instance. Also just spawning a new process for this function won't do because it will lose its context to the instance and won't be able to emit the event as well.